# Alien artefact on spaceship turns crew member into a killer

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember seeing a movie around 2000-2005 on the premium channels (HBO, Showtime, etc.).  I believe that it had a wide release, but I'm not sure.  It was American, in English, and in color.

The movie is about a space ship (I think they're some sort of hospital spaceship or science ship) that responds to an emergency.  They end up with this alien artifact on board.  A crew member (or someone they saved from the emergency) becomes obsessed with the artifact, and it starts to change him.  He ends up going psychotic and kills most everyone save the captain(?) and a black woman.

The movie ends with the white guy and black woman using a pod to escape the explosion of the alien artifact.  During the pod jump, the two end up swapping some dna because they shared the same pod, and the woman becomes pregnant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you mean [Supernova](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0134983/combined), with Robin Tunney from Mentalist. The black officer is Angela Bassett, also has James Spader. The one that goes crazy, if I remember correctly, is Peter Facinelli, who plays Karl.

Comment: i cant believe this answer gives Tunney top billing, lol. good call though.